# How to initiate TextView in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am new to fragments and have the following code:

```
public class TripleTab1 extends Fragment {

private TextView nameAndNumberText;
private Map<String, String> nameToNumberMapping;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){

    nameAndNumberText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.numberToNameView);
    nameToNumberMapping = ContactNameAndNumberUtility
            .getNameToPhoneNumberMapping(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext());

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : nameToNumberMapping.entrySet()) {
        String key = item.getKey();
        String value = item.getValue();

        nameAndNumberText.append(key);
        nameAndNumberText.append(value);
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.assign_pattern_tab_1, container, false);

}

}
```

Unfortunately, this gives me a NullPointerException. It seems like the TextView object is not initiated, even though I believe it should be.

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void android.widget.TextView.append(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
>   null object reference"

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: you are inflating your view at the end but declaring your widget before it. And you need to pass that inflated view to your widget to initialize them.

Comment: Why are you trying to get the view from the Activity inside the Fragment? The Fragment should only access its own views?

Comment: first print Log  of String key and String value before .append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.assign_pattern_tab_1, container, false);
    nameAndNumberText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.numberToNameView);
    nameToNumberMapping = ContactNameAndNumberUtility
            .getNameToPhoneNumberMapping(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext());

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : nameToNumberMapping.entrySet()) {
        String key = item.getKey();
        String value = item.getValue();

        nameAndNumberText.append(key);
        nameAndNumberText.append(value);
    }
    return view;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do like this:

Need to pass view to your `widgets` instead of `activity` and you are `inflating` your view at the end take it to the top.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assign_pattern_tab_1, container, false);
 nameAndNumberText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.numberToNameView);
nameToNumberMapping = ContactNameAndNumberUtility
        .getNameToPhoneNumberMapping(getActivity()
        .getApplicationContext());

for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : nameToNumberMapping.entrySet()) {
    String key = item.getKey();
    String value = item.getValue();

    nameAndNumberText.append(key);
    nameAndNumberText.append(value);
}
return v;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a View first

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assign_pattern_tab_1, container,false); 
nameAndNumberText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.numberToNameView);
        nameToNumberMapping = ContactNameAndNumberUtility
                .getNameToPhoneNumberMapping(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext());

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : nameToNumberMapping.entrySet()) {
            String key = item.getKey();
            String value = item.getValue();

            nameAndNumberText.append(key);
            nameAndNumberText.append(value);
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.assign_pattern_tab_1, container, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this:-

```
public class TripleTab1 extends Fragment {

private TextView nameAndNumberText;
private Map<String, String> nameToNumberMapping;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assign_pattern_tab_1, container, false);
    nameAndNumberText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.numberToNameView);
    nameToNumberMapping = ContactNameAndNumberUtility
            .getNameToPhoneNumberMapping(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext());

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : nameToNumberMapping.entrySet()) {
        String key = item.getKey();
        String value = item.getValue();

        nameAndNumberText.append(key);
        nameAndNumberText.append(value);
    }
    return v;

}
```